# pyspark kafka structured streaming tuning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

i want more faster kafka structured streaming without increase server.

when i understood structured streaming, kafka bootstrap.servers config is kafka message reader.

example) 3 servers link 1partition topic then work only 1 server, and 3 servers link 3partition topic then work 3 servers

then what is executor.cores and memory???

when i search about structured streaming, 1core = 1server = 1partition, so i config changed but not increase performance

this is my code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType,IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://server1:7077")\
    .appName("appName") \
    .config("spark.jars", "jarFiles") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.connection.uri", "mongodb://mongodb:mongodb@server2:27017/datahub.bigdata1") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores","2") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "4") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory","2g") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

schema1 = StructType() \
    .add("idx", StringType(), False) \
    .add("job", StringType(), True) \
    .add("company", StringType(), True) \
    .add("ssn", StringType(), True) \
    .add("residence", StringType(), True) \
    .add("blood_group", StringType(), True) \
    .add("username", StringType(), True) \
    .add("name", StringType(), True) \
    .add("sex", StringType(), True) \
    .add("address", StringType(), True) \
    .add("mail", StringType(), True)

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1:9092,server2:9092,server3:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "kafkaTopic") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("startingOffsets","earliest") \
    .load() \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("String"), schema1).alias("parsed_value")) \
    .select("parsed_value.*")

ds = df.writeStream \
  .format("mongodb") \
  .option("checkpointLocation","/home/mongo/streaming/") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
```

this is my test results

[image]

Comment: Kafka has its own consumer configs to increase consumption rates, such as `max.poll.records` and `max.poll.interval.ms`... Regarding executors, you cannot have more than the number of topic partitions reading at once, but when data is shuffled after that, there could be more used, but no more cores / memory than is totally available per node (more doesn't mean faster)

Comment: By the way, Spark isn't necessary if you choose to use Mongo Kafka Connector https://www.mongodb.com/kafka-connector

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you, but my boss wanted kafka to mongodb on spark :(. By the way, i know spark executor-kafka partition default match is 1:1 match. Then why reduced time at cores 2->4?? Was created Kafka replica 3 partition 3, then need 3executor for 1:1match.  When i allocate cores on Each server 2cores then total executor 4 and executor cores 1, satisfy for 1:1match. I cannot understand reduce time reason

Comment: @OneCricketeer and have you used minPartition??

Comment: I dont really use Spark, personally, but I've seen someone mention that Kafka Spark library will automatically reduce its resource utilization based on topic-partition count, but when you use something like `writeStream`, there could be more executors used since the data would all be in-memory